# Tikz matrix: Align node to center of multirow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices

I am having an issue with TIKZ, or matrices ... I don't know which :)

All I want to do is to move/align my Blackbox in the center of this one (multi-)row while having the arrows spread evenly on the sides (see below).
Somehow it does not work. I tried with tabular and array, but still no luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

(I'm no hero with latex, please be kind!)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usepackage{multirow} %
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows} %
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}%
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}%
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=black!85, text width=8em, text centered, text=white, rounded corners, minimum height=10em},
    line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex}]

    \matrix [column sep=15mm,row sep=6mm]
    {
    \node[] (in1) {Eingang 1} ; & \multirow{6}{*}{\node[block] (bb) {Blackbox};} & \node[] (out1) {Ausgang 1} ; \\
    \node[] (in2) {Eingang 2} ; & & \node[] (out2) {Ausgang 2} ; \\
    \node[] (in3) {Eingang 3} ; & & \node[] (out3) {Ausgang 3} ; \\
    \node[] (in4) {Eingang 4} ; & & \node[] (out4) {Ausgang 4} ; \\
    \node[] (in5) {Eingang 5} ; & & \node[] (out5) {Ausgang 5} ; \\
    \node[] (in6) {Eingang 6} ; & & \node[] (out6) {Ausgang 6} ; \\
    };

    \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
    \path (in1.east) -- ([yshift=3em]bb.west);
    \path (in2.east) -- ([yshift=2em]bb.west);
    \path (in3.east) -- ([yshift=1em]bb.west);
    \path (in4.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]bb.west);
    \path (in5.east) -- ([yshift=-2em]bb.west);
    \path (in6.east) -- ([yshift=-3em]bb.west);

    \path ([yshift=3em]bb.east) -- (out1.west);
    \path ([yshift=2em]bb.east) -- (out2.west);
    \path ([yshift=1em]bb.east) -- (out3.west);
    \path ([yshift=-1em]bb.east) -- (out4.west);
    \path ([yshift=-2em]bb.east) -- (out5.west);
    \path ([yshift=-3em]bb.east) -- (out6.west);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: align blackbox]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

The following method first places the two sets of nodes on both sides, which creates a bounding box. Then, it puts the black box at the center of the bounding box. You need to load the `positioning` library. And seems that the `automata` library is not needed.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usepackage{multirow} %
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} %
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}%
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}%
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=black!85, text width=8em, text centered, text=white, rounded corners, minimum height=10em},
    line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex}]

    \node(in1){Eingang 1};
    \foreach\innum[count=\inlag] in {2,...,6}
        \node(in\innum)[below=of in\inlag]{Eingang \innum};

    \node(out1)[right=50mm of in1]{Ausgang 1};
    \foreach\outnum[count=\outlag] in {2,...,6}
        \node(out\outnum)[below=of out\outlag]{Ausgang \outnum};

    \node[block] (bb) at(current bounding box.center) {Blackbox};

    \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
    \path (in1.east) -- ([yshift=3em]bb.west);
    \path (in2.east) -- ([yshift=2em]bb.west);
    \path (in3.east) -- ([yshift=1em]bb.west);
    \path (in4.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]bb.west);
    \path (in5.east) -- ([yshift=-2em]bb.west);
    \path (in6.east) -- ([yshift=-3em]bb.west);

    \path ([yshift=3em]bb.east) -- (out1.west);
    \path ([yshift=2em]bb.east) -- (out2.west);
    \path ([yshift=1em]bb.east) -- (out3.west);
    \path ([yshift=-1em]bb.east) -- (out4.west);
    \path ([yshift=-2em]bb.east) -- (out5.west);
    \path ([yshift=-3em]bb.east) -- (out6.west);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This looks really good!
Only thing is, I get an Emergency Stop on 
   \usetikzlibrary{ arrows, positioning} %
Can't find file `tikzlibraryauto.code.tex'.

What do I need to use this library?

Comment: @gilu: Sorry. I think I mistakenly left the `auto` in the `\usetikzlibrary` command (it was meant to be `automata` but I guess I didn't delete it fully). Error corrected now.

Comment: No problem! This works really well, too!
It's most elegant, since I could also loop the arrows and make it more adaptive...

Answer (score 5):

What you have is a `matrix` of nodes in which `\multirow` won't work. You have to a new row at the center for the black box. To change the excess vertical space, you can use `\\[<dimen>]` as in

```
\node[] (in3) {Eingang 3} ; & & \node[] (out3) {Ausgang 3} ; \\[-2.3cm]
                  &    \node[block] (bb) {Blackbox};   &          \\[-2.3cm]
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usepackage{multirow} %
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows} %
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}%
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}%
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=black!85, text width=8em, text centered, text=white, rounded corners, minimum height=10em},
    line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex}]

    \matrix [column sep=15mm,row sep=6mm]
    {
    \node[] (in1) {Eingang 1} ; &  & \node[] (out1) {Ausgang 1} ; \\
    \node[] (in2) {Eingang 2} ; & & \node[] (out2) {Ausgang 2} ; \\
    \node[] (in3) {Eingang 3} ; & & \node[] (out3) {Ausgang 3} ; \\[-2.3cm]
                  &    \node[block] (bb) {Blackbox};   &          \\[-2.3cm]
    \node[] (in4) {Eingang 4} ; & & \node[] (out4) {Ausgang 4} ; \\
    \node[] (in5) {Eingang 5} ; & & \node[] (out5) {Ausgang 5} ; \\
    \node[] (in6) {Eingang 6} ; & & \node[] (out6) {Ausgang 6} ; \\
    };

    \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
    \path (in1.east) -- ([yshift=3em]bb.west);
    \path (in2.east) -- ([yshift=2em]bb.west);
    \path (in3.east) -- ([yshift=1em]bb.west);
    \path (in4.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]bb.west);
    \path (in5.east) -- ([yshift=-2em]bb.west);
    \path (in6.east) -- ([yshift=-3em]bb.west);

    \path ([yshift=3em]bb.east) -- (out1.west);
    \path ([yshift=2em]bb.east) -- (out2.west);
    \path ([yshift=1em]bb.east) -- (out3.west);
    \path ([yshift=-1em]bb.east) -- (out4.west);
    \path ([yshift=-2em]bb.east) -- (out5.west);
    \path ([yshift=-3em]bb.east) -- (out6.west);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That will work!!

So ... you changed the margin to a negativ number on two rows?!
This I don't understand how that works .. :\

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do now, thanks to all of you who answered!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usepackage{multirow} %
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} %
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}%
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}%
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=black!85, text width=8em, text centered, text=white, rounded corners, minimum height=10em},
    line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex},
    nodel/.style={text width=9em, align=right, anchor=east}, % change width for long text
    noder/.style={text width=9em, align=left, anchor=west}    
    ]

    \node(in1){}; %Eingang 1
    \foreach\innum[count=\inlag] in {2,...,6}
        \node(in\innum)[below=of in\inlag]{}; %Eingang \innum

    \node(out1)[right=60mm of in1]{}; %Ausgang 1
    \foreach\outnum[count=\outlag] in {2,...,6}
        \node(out\outnum)[below=of out\outlag]{}; %Ausgang \outnum

    \node[block] (bb) at(current bounding box.center) {Blackbox};

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style=nodel]
        \node[] at (in1) {This is really long text for only one node};
        \node[] at (in2) {Very short!};
        \node[] at (in3) {Here's some more text that needs to fit my node};
        \node[] at (in4) {Here's some more text};
        \node[] at (in5) {Nothing new here};
        \node[] at (in6) {Nothing new here};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style=noder]
        \node[] at (out1) {Not as much};
        \node[] at (out2) {Long text, see above};
        \node[] at (out3) {Short! Or maybe not as short as I thought. Maybe too much};
        \node[] at (out4) {Short};
        \node[] at (out5) {Something else over here};
        \node[] at (out6) {Something else over here};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
        \path (in1.east) -- ([yshift=3em]bb.west);
        \path (in2.east) -- ([yshift=2em]bb.west);
        \path (in3.east) -- ([yshift=1em]bb.west);
        \path (in4.east) -- ([yshift=-1em]bb.west);
        \path (in5.east) -- ([yshift=-2em]bb.west);
        \path (in6.east) -- ([yshift=-3em]bb.west);

        \path ([yshift=3em]bb.east) -- (out1.west);
        \path ([yshift=2em]bb.east) -- (out2.west);
        \path ([yshift=1em]bb.east) -- (out3.west);
        \path ([yshift=-1em]bb.east) -- (out4.west);
        \path ([yshift=-2em]bb.east) -- (out5.west);
        \path ([yshift=-3em]bb.east) -- (out6.west);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]